# Cerebellar tonsil herniation measurement level?

Tags: brain, mri, tall-height

In my MRI scan result the cerebellar tonsil detected had a measurement of 0.50 mm through the foremen magnum. Is this condition considered normal for a tall person or is it considered the beginning of cerebellar tonsil herniation?

Comment: What did the person who ordered the MRI say when you asked them?

Comment: @JohnP according to him its nothing serious and have yearly based CT scan for make sure everything normal and it not push down any further while i was check with another doctor , he mention its very serious condition . What i want to know is it normal for tall person can born with extra long compare normal condition which 5mm below ?